# How to serialize an RSAKey to a raw string using Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

With `paramiko`, I can generate an instance of a private [`RSAKey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/keys.html#module-paramiko.rsakey) from a string using this call:

```py
private_key_string = "******"
rsa_key = paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey(data=private_key_string)
```

However, once I have that instance, how can I convert it back to the original string used to generate it? There is [`write_private_key`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.write_private_key), but writes the key out in OpenSSH-format, which doesn't work for this purpose:

```py
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> buffer = StringIO()
>>> key.write_private_key(buffer)
>>> RSAKey(data=buffer.getvalue().encode())

SSHException: Invalid key (class: RSAKey, data type: -BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
******
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there a way serialize an instance of `RSAKey` to a format that can be consumed by `RSAKey(data=raw_key)`?

Comment: Is it really a private key? The `data` parameter is typically used for public keys. How did you obtain the value of `private_key_string`?

Comment: The value of data is retrieved from an Airflow connection configuration in this case. I am certain it is a private key, I have generated it myself. I am also able to use this object for private key authentication.